# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run the following which is throwing an

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'objects'

**script.py**

```
#Get Dota2 Item Rarities
dotaItemRarityUrl = 'http://api.steampowered.com/IEconDOTA2_570/GetRarities/v1?'
dotaItemRarityPayload = {'key': settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_STEAM_API_KEY,
                    'language': 'en',
                    }
dotaItemRarityInfo = requests.get(dotaItemRarityUrl, params=dotaItemRarityPayload)
dotaItemRarity = dotaItemRarityInfo.json()
dotaItemRarity = dotaItemRarity['result']['rarities']
print(dotaItemRarity)
#print(dotaItemQualities)

#Populate Database With Item Rarities that do NOT exist already
for rarity in dotaItemRarity:
    print rarity
    irarityId = rarity['id']
    irarityProperName = rarity['localized_name']
    irarityInternalName = rarity['name']
    irarityColor = rarity['color']

    q = dotaItemRarity.objects.filter(rarityId=irarityId)
    print q

    if len(q) == 0:
        newRarity = dotaItemRarity(rarityId=irarityId,
                                   rarityProperName=irarityProperName,
                                   rarityInternalName=irarityInternalName,
                                   rarityColor=irarityColor)
        newRarity.save()
```

**models.py**

```
class dotaItemRarity(models.Model):
    rarityId = models.IntegerField(max_length=3,primary_key=True)
    rarityProperName = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    rarityInternalName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rarityColor = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.rarityInternalName
```

I am using south to handle migrations and have tried multiple options to fix this e.g. removing the tables and rebuilt them. As far as I can tell this should work, can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: You define a list called `dotaItemRarity`, which shadows the model you imported with the same name. Rename your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dotaItemRarity` is a list, and it has no `objects` attribute:

```
q = dotaItemRarity.objects.filter(rarityId=irarityId)
```

That's because you bound it to a list from your JSON result:

```
dotaItemRarity = dotaItemRarityInfo.json()
dotaItemRarity = dotaItemRarity['result']['rarities']
```

It is **not** a Django model, as you appear to expect it to be.

If you had the `dotaItemRarity` Django model imported into `script.py`, then the name is no longer bound to that model, as you replaced it with the list.

Rename the list to use a different name that doesn't mask the model.

Note that the [Python style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) recommends that you use CamelCase names for classes (including Django models), to avoid such mistakes.

Following PEP 8 to refactor your code a little, as well as using some clearer naming an practices:

`models.py`:

```
class DotaItemRarity(models.Model):
    rarity_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=3, primary_key=True)
    rarity_proper_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    rarity_internal_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rarity_color = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.rarity_internal_name
```

`script.py`:

```
#Get Dota2 Item Rarities
url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/IEconDOTA2_570/GetRarities/v1'
payload = {'key': settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_STEAM_API_KEY, 'language': 'en'}
response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
rarities = response.json()['result']['rarities']

for rarity in rarities:
    rarity_id = rarity['id']

    try:
        DotaItemRarity.get(rarity_id=rarity_id)
    except DotaItemRarity.DoesNotExist:
        new_rarity = DotaItemRarity(
            rarityId=rarity_id,
            rarity_proper_name=rarity['localized_name'],
            rarity_internal_name=rarity['name'],
            rarity_color=rarity['color'])
        new_rarity.save()
```

Comment: Wow... thanks a lot. Silly mistake on my part but thanks for pointing me in the right direction in terms of best practice. This should help to avoid this happening again.